# Swap 2 nodes of a single linked list. i have the program. I need to ask where its wrong

Tags: linked-list

I wrote the following program. The swap is working fine if i debug it. However i am not able to return the complete linked list. It is changing the head as well. what is wrong?

```
public static Node<Integer> swapElementsAtiAndj(Node<Integer> head, int i, int j)
{

    Node<Integer> temp= head;
    Node<Integer> prev1  = temp;
    Node<Integer> prev2  = temp;
    Node<Integer> toSwap1  = temp;
    Node<Integer> toSwap2  = temp;
    int count =0;
    int pos1 =i;
    int pos2 =j;
    if(i>j) {
        pos1 = j;
        pos2 =i;
    }
    while (count !=pos1) {
        prev1 = toSwap1;
        toSwap1 = toSwap1.next;
        prev2 = prev1;
        toSwap2 = toSwap1;
        count++;
    }

    while(count != pos2) {
        prev2 = toSwap2;
        toSwap2 = toSwap2.next;
        count++;
    }
    temp.data = toSwap1.data;
    temp.next = toSwap2.next;
    toSwap2.next = toSwap1.next;
    prev2.next = temp;
    prev1.next = toSwap2;


    return head;
}
```

Comment: You modify temp which is head. BTW: you should not initialise variables with values you dont need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your `head` is getting modified at

```
temp.next = toSwap2.next;
```

Because `temp` is pointing at `head`. Here is how you can fix it:
First of all,

```
prev2 = prev1;
toSwap2 = toSwap1;
```

can be written outside of `while` loop.

Now, after second `while` loop `toSwap1` and `toSwap2` are pointing at elements to be swapped.

```
// Swap prev
prev1.next = toSwap2;
prev2.next = toSwap1;

// Store toSwap2's next in temp
temp = toSwap2.next;

// Set toSwap2's next to toSwap1's next
toSwap2.next = toSwap1.next;

// Set toSwap1's next to old toSwap2's next (i.e temp)
toSwap1.next = temp;

// Return
return head;
```